# Use setKeepWithNext in IText7.0.2

Tags: java, itext

[image]

I need to keep more than one paragraph in the same area. See the image, I want title "Proposal Summary Report", solid line, and next paragraph in the same area. When I used the method setKeepWithNext, it just keep two paragraph in the same area. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the remaining space available on the page, and compare that to the height of the elements you want to render. If there is not enough room to have all of these elements on the same page, insert a new page and then insert the elements.

The wonderful thing about this approach is that it becomes very modular. You can create a virtual element used solely for grouping elements together that imbues this logic. Then, whenever you want elements held together, use this container-element to ensure the logic.